# Play Framework controller with secure and non-secure methods. Possible?

Tags: security, controller, playframework

I try to make a website with play with a member and a non member area. So i have controllers with member and non-member methods. But i can only make the whole controller secure [@With(Secure.class)].
Is it possibly to make only a few methods secure and access the others without a login?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can to this. Remove @With annotation and use this method of Secure controller when you want restrict access to connected user :

```
Secure.checkAccess();
```

With this method, you can even use @Check annotation. Example :

```
    @Check("member")
    public static void restrictedAction() {
        Secure.checkAccess();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: have you ever tried to call the checkAccess method from a controller within a module? It does not seem to work. It throws an error that the method is not visible. Indeed, when you see the definition of the method, it is not specified as public by default. How come does it then work without any problems in the app controllers?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, although it will require some tweaking on the Secure class. If you check @Secure it has a method annotated with @Before. As per [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/controllers#Before) you can indicate which methods the @Before is applied to and for which ones it is skipped.

```
@Before(unless="login")
```

So it would be a matter of not running @Before on the public methods. Be aware it may not work properly using @With and you may need to create your own @Before in the controller that manages the security (calling the proper methods in secure).

But it would be simpler to just have 2 controllers, one for secure users and one for public methods.

Comment: My upvote goes for the suggestion of two controllers. I came to this question because of the 'Before' annotation not working properly with an 'unless' array of method names that should skip. You mention it might not work properly using 'With', which is my case. Do you have any more information on why is that? Bug, or design side effect? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the deadbolt module which is quite powerful: http://www.playframework.org/modules/deadbolt

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no simple way to do this. You can check roles, but not connected user, visitor.

You would have to add `@Before` annotations and that is going to be a little complicated. Simply break up your controller into several controllers. It is by the way, functionnaly better to do it that way, rather than mix up public/private methods.